# Specify transparent background color?

Tags: transparency

I use Python-Sphinx to document some Python code I wrote. I'm using the `pngmath` extension to render LaTeX math expressions. The problem is, the background-color of the rendered images is white and the background color on which the images are shown differs from page to page. I can set the background color with

```
\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{%color%}
```

but there does not seem to be a transparent color. How can I make the background color of the images transparent?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, there is no transparent background color. The transparency needs to be a property of the image itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `-bg Transparent` to `dvipng` works fine.

### Note

The Python-Sphinx documentation says

> When you “add” an argument, you need to reproduce the default arguments if you want to keep
>   them; that is, like this:
>
> pngmath_dvipng_args = ['-gamma 1.5', '-D 110', '-bg Transparent']

-- [Math support in Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/math.html#confval-pngmath_dvipng_args)

But in the configuration file, this has to be

```
pngmath_dvipng_args = ['gamma', '1.5', '-D', '110', '-bg', 'Transparent']
# or
pngmath_dvipng_args = 'gamma 1.5 -D 110 -bg Transparent'.split()
```